# Why javascript data type `number` is only made of double precision?

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

AFAIK, double takes more space than float, so it is better to deal with precise number.

But I was wondering why and researched but had no luck.

There could have been multiple types of number like other languages do.

Were there any purpose on this design?

Comment: It has two: `number` and `BigInt`. Not really `double`.

Comment: [Very relevant for "why" type of questions on language design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Aren't `number` and `BigInt` implementation of javascript base number type(=double)?

Comment: The word "double" has no meaning in JavaScript. BigInts are integers only.

Comment: @JunKim `BigInt` is definitely not `number`. Otherwise, we wouldn't have two different things one of which is way more recent. `BigInt` are integers with wider possible safe range than the normal number type.

Comment: I see. I just found this link(https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/essential-guide-javascript-newest-data-type-bigint/) and the BigInt data type is not a type of number but a whole new data type.

I would like to correct my question, why `number` type is only made of double?

Comment: OK, let me counter that question with another one: why not?

Comment: `double takes more space than float, so it is better to deal with precise number.` as I've written above. So I thought it could have been better to deal with memory size if there are multiple number types. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So, your claim is that space for holding numbers is a concern that needs addressing? If so, was this a pressing concern over the last 20 years? If it was, then it wasn't solved, so it seems it wasn't *that* pressing.

Comment: I am not claiming or addressing this as an issue. But I am just curious if there was any reason while I am deep diving into javascript learning.

Comment: The need for other types (from 8-bit int to 64-bit) only seemed to be relevant for arrays of numbers, so JS has [indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects#indexed_collections): Uint8Array, Float32Array, etc.

Comment: "*I am not claiming or addressing this as an issue*" then it seems that you're not proposing any incentive for adding other datatypes. Without a reason, why would you expect anybody to design, discuss, spec, and implement other numeric types? Please read the article I've linked - "why" something isn't in a language is not a very useful question to ask.

Comment: I don't know what part of my comment is misleading but to clarify, `you're not proposing any incentive for adding other datatypes. ` -> Using a size-limited number type could reduce the memory size was my first intuition. ` why would you expect anybody to design, discuss, spec, and implement other numeric types? ` -> I am not expecting anything to be changed or somebody to have designed. I am just curious if there was any reason for that. Maybe for easy-use could be a reason or 'No reason' also could be a reason. I will check the link you provided tho, thanks.

Comment: "*Using a size-limited number type could reduce the memory size was my first intuition*" yet when I asked if this was a problem needing resolving you said that it isn't. So, is this worth spending time on or not? "*I am not expecting anything to be changed or somebody to have designed*" if you don't expect anybody to spend the time on this, then it seems there is no reason to have multiple number types. Neither me nor mostly anybody else on the site can give concrete reasoning for every single language feature. In most cases, it's not really relevant, either.